# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working on a jquery mobile script to get json from my wordpress site but its not displaying anything and returns with a: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' error. I know i'm messing up somewhere with parsing the json, but i happen to be a javascript noob. To the guy that both fixes and explains it to me, i thank you.

HTML:
ListView

```
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="content">
        <div class="example-wrapper" data-iscroll>
            <ul data-role="listview" id="post-list" data-theme="a"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PageView

```
<div data-role="page" id="headline">
 <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="post-data" data-theme="a"></ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function () {

                   $.ajax({
                          url: 'http://chris.floppytron.com/api/get_recent_posts/',
                          dataType: "jsonp",
                          success: function (result) {
                          ajax.parseJSONP(result);
                          },
                          error: function (request, error) {
                          alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                          }
                          });
                   });

                   $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#headline', function () {
                                  $('#post-data').empty();
                                  $.each(postInfo.result, function (i, row) {
                                         if (row.id == postInfo.id) {
                                         $('#post-data').append('<li>' + row.title + '</li>');
                                         $('#post-data').append('<li>' + row.date + '</li>');
                                         $('#post-data').append('<li>' + row.categories + '</li><br />');
                                         $('#post-data').append('<li>' + row.content + '</li>');
                                         $('#post-data').listview('refresh');
                                         }
                                         });
                                  });

                                  $(document).on('vclick', '#post-list li a', function () {
                                                 postInfo.id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                                                 $.mobile.changePage("#headline", {
                                                                     transition: "slide",
                                                                     changeHash: false
                                                                     });
                                                 });

                                                 var postInfo = {
                                                     id: null,
                                                     result: null
                                                 }

var ajax = {
    parseJSONP: function (result) {
        postInfo.result = result.results;
        $.each(result.results, function (i, row) {
               console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
               $('#post-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.id + '"><img src="' + row.thumbnail + '"/><h3>' + row.title + '</h3><p>' + row.categories + '</p><br /><p>' + row.date + '</p></a></li>');
               });
               $('#post-list').listview('refresh');
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea where it is blowing up on you.

Comment: can you check the value of `postInfo.result` - if you pass undefined as the first param to `$.each()` you can get the said error. Also `result.results`

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no function `$.parseJSONP` it's `$.parseJSON` without "P". Anyway, you don't need to parse the returned Ajax result since it is ready to be populated.
2. The returned array has no `.results` property, it is `.posts`.

   ```
   postInfo.result = result.posts;
   $.each(postInfo.result, function (i, row) {
   ```

Fixed code

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#home', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://chris.floppytron.com/api/get_recent_posts/',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (result) {
            addRows(result);
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#headline', function () {
    $('#post-data').empty();
    $.each(postInfo.result, function (i, row) {
        if (row.id == postInfo.id) {
            $('#post-data').append('<li>' + row.title + '</li>');
            $('#post-data').append('<li>' + row.date + '</li>');
            $('#post-data').append('<li>' + row.categories + '</li><br />');
            $('#post-data').append('<li>' + row.content + '</li>');
            $('#post-data').listview('refresh');
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '#post-list li a', function () {
    postInfo.id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.mobile.changePage("#headline", {
        transition: "slide",
        changeHash: false
    });
});

var postInfo = {
    id: null,
    result: null
};

function addRows(result) {
    postInfo.result = result.posts;
    $.each(postInfo.result, function (i, row) {
        $('#post-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.id + '"><img src="' + row.thumbnail + '"/><h3>' + row.title + '</h3><p>' + row.categories + '</p><br /><p>' + row.date + '</p></a></li>');
    });
    $('#post-list').listview('refresh');
};
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6u50v1g1/)**